# How to delete tags that are between square brackets in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, parsing

I have a string:

```py
my_string = "[some tag1][tag 2] Some text"
```

How can I delete the tags from the string in Python 3?

Comment: What have you tried?  The `re` module and `re.sub` would work for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex:

```
import re

my_string =  " [The Tag before the text works] The text [The Tag after the text does not work]"

result = re.sub(r'\s*\[.+?\]\s*', '', my_string)
```

The `lstrip()` will strip away the whitespace between the tags and the text.

Comment: It works, but with a problem. But I also have the lines " [The Tag before the text works] The text [The Tag after the text does not work]". If the tag is after the text, the text becomes empty.

Comment: That is a greedy quantifier.. that will match the last `]` and only due to backtracking. Consider making a negative character class or use a reluctant quantifier.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I changed the quantifier to non-greedy. I also remove  any whitespace before and after the brackets.